# EdmAssociationConstraint: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am having EdmAssociationConstraint: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint this exception in EF 5

I want to fix this issue using data annotation

```
public class Task
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TaskId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Trigger
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TriggerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public virtual Task Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class TriggerHistory
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TriggerHistoryId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int TriggerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskId")]
    public virtual Trigger Triggers { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Trigger class has composit key (TriggerId, TaskId).
But your TriggerHistory has Trigger navigation property with `ForeignKey` defined using only TaskId property.

Try to change `ForeignKey` on Triggers property like this:

```
[ForeignKey("TriggerId,TaskId")]
public virtual Trigger Triggers { get; set; }
```

And maybe the Triggers property should be named "Trigger" as this is not the collection of Trigger objects.

Comment: I did not know you could add multiple keys in the ForeignKey attribute.  Thanks!